# Remove button added by Workflow on View

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I would like to ask if it's possible to hide a button that was added by a workflow in view mode of a record. The workflow is locked so inactivating the action is not an option.

I'm trying to call client script on view mode of the record using user event script beforeLoad. The code goes something like this:

User Event script with form.setScript.

```
//User Event Script
function callClientScript(type, form) {
    if (type == 'view') {
        form.setScript('customscript_client_script');
    }
}
```

The client with id: customscript_client_script:

```
//Client Script
function removeButton() {
    document.getElementById('HTML Id of button to hide').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I've researched and all examples I've found uses a button to bind the client script so it runs when clicked. They add this line of code in the user event script:

```
form.addButton('custpage_my_button', 'Button Test', 'removeButton()');
```

I tested this and it works fine. However, I need to run the "removeButton()" function automatically after the page loads.

Comment: Is the clientscript running on pageInit? If not, then try it.

Comment: @AdolfoGarza Hi, the client script is not deployed. Actually it doesn't need to be based on my researches. But then, I still tried putting the function in the pageInit but still doesn't work. Thanks for the comment tho.

Comment: It doesn't need to be if you are calling it from UserEvent, but it does if you are using just clientscript. Try it without Userevent.

Comment: Nevermind, clientscript doesnt run on view mode. You need to inject the code using the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you need to use some hacking of the DOM. You need to inject the javascript using an inlineHTML body field created during beforeLoad with your clientscript code as a string set as default value and surrounded by `<script>` tags.

Something like this in Suitescript 2.0:

```
var injectScriptField = form.addField({
        id : 'custpage_injectscript',
        type : UIMODULE.FieldType.INLINEHTML,
        label : 'Inject Script Field'
    });
injectScriptField.defaultValue = '<script>alert("Hello");</script>';
```

Comment: Hey @AdolfoGarza, this worked! Thanks so much.
I didn't know I could do that with inlineHTML.

Just curious tho, is this field hidden by default? Cause I can't find it anywhere on the transaction. Also to add, I tried setting the field to hidden and for some reason, it doesn't work.

Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think the field is hidden, you should be able to see the label at least. Maybe it was loaded under the Custom tab.